# Не работает событие js

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Итак начну с начала - описание характеристик страницы:
1) HTML-код
2) Подключен jquery 2 compressed
В конце страницы после тега `</html>` пишу:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function remove(id){
    $.post(
  "work/panel4.php",
  {
    code: id
  },
  onAjaxSuccess
);

function onAjaxSuccess(data)
{
alert(data)
}
}
</script>
```

Для любителей кэширования напишу - если через chrome сделать view-source то грузится актуальный код, так вот, сделал я `<img src="1.jpg" onclick="remove(1);">` , так вот, изображение выводится, кликаю по нему - 0 результатов, пытаюсь сделать событие в консоли - пишу remove(1), все ок, всплывает alert, проверяю - действительно все ок, то есть не работает именно событие,помогите исправить...

Comment: а вот не вешайте ваши события через `onclick="..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вместо того чтобы грузить скрипт после тэга html (кто вам такое посоветовал?) вставляйте скрипт в хедер(после загрузки jQuery) в таком вот виде:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {

$('img.clickable').click(remove);   
function remove(){
var id=$(this).data('id');
    $.post(
  "work/panel4.php",
  {
    code: id
  },
  onAjaxSuccess
);

function onAjaxSuccess(data)
{
   alert(data)
}
}
});
</script>
```

и добавьте к вашим img на которые можно кликать class="clickable" и data т.е. элемент должен выглядеть:

```
 <img src="1.jpg" class="clickable" data-id="1">
```

конечно есть варианты как это реализовывать,  но точно не так как вы сделали.